# Error message "there is no package called 'tibble'" when trying to import data into R

Tags: r, import

I'm trying to import a dataset into R. When I try to run the code I used to do this previously, the read_csv function no longer works. I tried importing the data manually by using the "import data" dropdown button instead. When I click on this, I get the error message "there is no package called 'tibble'" and cannot import the dataset. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: have you called `library(tibble)`? you need to give us more info than this. give us the output from `library(tibble)` and the version of R you are using. Als the version of the tibble package you have.

Comment: This is what happens when I call the library. > library(tibble)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tibble’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘pkgconfig’ 2.0.1 is being loaded, but >= 2.0.2 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tibble’ was built under R version 3.4.4

Comment: looks like its not installed then... type `install.packages('tibble')`

Comment: I tried to install it just before I got that error message. I'm trying again.

Comment: did the install say it finished successfuly? or did it also error?

Comment: It errored the first 3 times I tried but worked the 4th...not sure why. It looks like it's all working now.

Comment: sometimes packages need dependencies, so if you are missing those or their install fails it can make the whole thing error. In these situations always read the error messages carefully as they are usually very self-explanatory. If you still don't understand them, google the exact error message and you will probably find an answer